# Do I need to specify matches within content_scripts for Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to submit my chrome extension for review. If I specify a matches field within content_scripts, I get this warning message from the dashboard.
[image: warning]

When I leave the matches field empty, the warning goes away but then I can no longer test it locally. I get the following:
[image: localError]

I do not actually need to specify the matches field for my uses, but I'm worried that since it's not running locally it might be a problem when it's published. Is it okay if I leave the matches array empty in my manfest.json?

Here is my manifest.json for reference:

```
{
"name": "DraftToCalendar",
"description": "blah blah",
"version": "0.1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"key": "bigKey",
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "bigGoogleKey,
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    ]
},
"icons": {
    "16": "./calendar-icon.png",
    "48": "./calendar-icon.png",
    "128": "./calendar-icon.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            
        ],
        "js": [
            "script1.js",
            "script2.js",
           "content.js"
        ]
    }
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "DraftToCalendar",
    "default_popup": "./index.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "activeTab"
]
```

}

Comment: As the error message says `matches` can't be empty. An empty `matches` means the entire content_scripts section is meaningless so either specify a valid URL pattern in `matches` or remove the section.